Results from two tables with DISTINCT
I have a query which returns all unique values from a table.
punches table:
SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
FROM punches 
WHERE organisation_id  = '$current_organisation_id';

This will list of user_id's.
I also need to get the result of "name" of each user, that is stored in "user" table and also has "user_id" as primary key.
Many thanks
I could get this results with two different SQL queries, but I know it is possible to do in one query.

Do you want the unique user_id, user_name combinations where the user_id appears in punches?

you can try inner query or join query

You don't say which DB you're using but in MySQL I would use a LEFT JOIN.

Sounds like you actually need an IN or EXISTS query, with users as the outer table.
SELECT
  u.user_id,
  u.name
FROM users u
WHERE u.user_id IN (
    SELECT p.user_id
    FROM punches p
    WHERE p.organisation_id  = '$current_organisation_id'
);

I sincerely hope $current_organisation_id is not some kind of SQL injection. If so, you should be using a parameter
    WHERE p.organisation_id  = @current_organisation_id

